# Facebook getUser() returns 0

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication

I am implementing Facebook login using the PHP SDK with Codeigniter. I get the Facebook login popup, hit login, but I am unable to retrieve the user's id - it always returns 0.

I have put the facebook.php and base_facebook.php files in my libraries file and included it as a library in Codeigniter following a tutorial [here](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter).

Can anyone tell me what they think is going on? I am using the following code -

**View - Facebook login button**

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '<?php echo $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'); ?>',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });

          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
            window.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>auth_other/fb_signin/';
          });

    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

**Controller - auth_other/fb_signin**

```
    function fb_signin()
    {           
        $fb_user = null;

        $fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'),
        'secret' => $this->config->item('facebook_app_secret')
        );

        $this->load->library('facebook',$fb_config);

        $fb_user = $this->facebook->getUser();


        echo $fb_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck up with similar issue, here is the solution that may help you.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  "redirect_uri" => "set the uri to point to the same page"
 ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
//your task
} else {
header('location:'. $facebook->getLoginUrl());

}

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
//your task
} else {
header('location:'. $facebook->getLoginUrl());
```

}

Comment: The above code explanation is that if getUser() returns a 0 then we need to redirect with $facebook->getLoginUrl() to a page where the user will accept the application and get permissions, then getUser() will work if the user accepts otherwise you'll get 0 again.ù

Answer (score 0):

Came across a situation where getUser() was returning 0 when it really shouldn't be, the application was still sandboxed. Turns out the user hadn't accept the request to be developer of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem. I used an example project, and couldn't figure out why it keeps returning 0. tried nearly all related links here but none solved it.

The solution was to update Facebook's SDK files in the example project.
Simple and easily missed,

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, After long time of trying to figure out what the issue is, 
I found that you need access token to get user ID.
To get access token form the signed_request, user must authorize (to get permissions) you app firstly.
I hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

If App domain is real domain but site url is localhost, getUser function return 0

Comment: not correct, the above works even under localhost if you indicate canvas url as "http://localhost/my-great-app/" and under app domains "localhost"